# Как увидеть значение своего класса String?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, отладка, qtcreator

Написал свой класс строки - `String`. Но увидеть значение переменной типа `String` в *Visual Studio* или *Qt Creator* не могу (занимаюсь переводом в `std::string`).

Как заставить IDE показывать значение таких переменных?

Comment: Есть метод, нужно указать Visual Studio, где брать нужную информацию. Напишу, как доберусь до компьютера.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Смотрите.

Для свежих версий Visual Studio (начиная с 2012) лучше всего пользоваться форматом natvis. При этом вы можете, например, включить визуализацию ваших типов прямо в проект, и Visual Studio даже будет подхватывать изменения отображения прямо на лету, во время отладки.

Давайте разберём простой пример. Создадим простейший кастомный класс, представляющий строку.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstring>

namespace utils
{
    class MyString
    {
        size_t length;
        char* payload;

    public:
        MyString() : length(0), payload(nullptr) { }
        MyString(char* data) : length(strlen(data)), payload(new char[length + 1])
        { strcpy_s(payload, length + 1, data); }

        ~MyString() { delete[] payload; }
    };
}
```

И простейший тест:

```
int main()
{
    utils::MyString s1;
    utils::MyString s2("I am string");
}
```

Теперь добавим нашу кастомную визуализацию. Для этого идём в окно проекта

[image: добавить файл...]

и добавляем новый natvis-файл. Назовём его MyString.natvis.

[image: ... добавили]

Получим следующий файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
</AutoVisualizer>
```

Добавим в него нашу визуализацию. Положим тег `Type` с именем нашего типа (включая namespace). Подтег `DisplayString` задаёт то, как тип будет отображаться в одну строку. Можно добавить условие (`DisplayString Condition=`), в зависимости от которого значение будет отображаться по-другому. Подтег `Expand` управляет тем, как будут отображаться данные в «распахнутом» виде. (Поскольку это XML, не забудьте, что `<` и `>` для шаблонных типов придётся вводить как `&lt;` и `&gt;`, наподобие `Name="std::vector&lt;*&gt;"`. Звёздочка используется для обозначения произвольного аргумента шаблона.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
  <Type Name="utils::MyString">
    <DisplayString Condition="payload == 0">[empty string]</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString>{payload,s}, len={length,d}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
      <Item Name="Length">length,d</Item>
      <Item Name="Content">payload, sb</Item>
    </Expand>
  </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

Получаем вот такую картинку в окошке Watch:

[image: а вот и результат]

Дополнительное чтение по теме:

- Подробная информация о синтаксисе natvis и его фичах находится [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx#Anchor_8).
- Обзор новых возможностей natvis в Visual Studio 2015 [здесь](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/09/28/debug-visualizers-in-visual-c-2015/).